# Google Places Autocomplete API Filtering by

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

Thanks for taking out some time to read this.

I'm working on a project that involves having to show autocomplete search hinting data for worldwide Cities,Airports,Hotels and Points of Interest.

I'm having a couple of issues when it comes to the google places Autocomplete API. I'm trying to filter by only City,Hotel,Airport and POI, but I noticed the places autocomplete API does not have this functionality out the box to the best of knowledge.

I would appreciate if some one can provide me some work arounds on what I can to to accomplish my current task.

Thanks I'm looking forward to some help. Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Places Autocomplete lets you filter results to `types: ['establishment']` ([example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete)), but not specific place types. You'd probably be interested in this feature request: [Issue 3538: Allow Places types in autocomplete](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3538)

Comment: is there a method to force local results to list first?  As an example, if my user is in Tampa to force returned results that match Tampa first...then list by geographic distance after that...Orlando, then Atlanta, etc  As of right now, my user starts entering an address or name its pulling matches from across the country first versus showing local matches first.  User has to keep tying to eventually get to local matches.

Comment: No such option exists, that would *force* exactly this, but adding a location+radius should help, and there is an option to force prediction to be all within that region by adding *strictbounds* ─ see https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#location_restrict

Comment: Actually, there is a method to do this.  Its the rankBy.DISTANCE option, the only problem is that it also requires the option of `keyword`, `type` or `name` - to me those options seem to require you already know what the user is searching for and this search would be like a sub-category search.  But my users could be searching for any category, keyword or type - so it won't really be effective for me.    If I use location+radius would that prevent users from doing lookups outside the the specified radius?

Comment: This sounds like you have questions about Nearby Search but this thread was about Autocomplete. I'd recommend you post a new question about this.